# Jbehave test Runner Issue

Tags: cucumber, bdd, jbehave

I am trying to implement BDD in my project and I'm using Jbehave for the same, I am referring the online materials available, I have created the story file, Steps class and the Runner class as below, but I'm getting some weird exception which I'm not able to resolve it.

1)  Story file, 'Sample.story'

```
Narrative:
In order to communicate effectively to the business some functionality
As a development team
I want to use Behaviour-Driven Development

Scenario:  A scenario is a collection of executable steps of different type
Given I type Hello
When Hit Enter
Then It prints Hellows
```

2) Steps definition file, 'SampleSteps.java'

```
package com.kar.features;

import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Given;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.Then;
import org.jbehave.core.annotations.When;

public class SampleSteps {

@Given("I type Hello")
public void TypeHello(){
    System.out.println("welcome to Cucumber");
}

@When ("Hit Enter")
public void SetBalanceToZero(){
    System.out.println("Inside the 'Enter' section");
}

@Then ("It prints Hellows")
public void addAmount(){
    System.out.println("I'm at the end");
}
}
```

3) The Runner Class, 'Sample.java'

```
package com.kar.features;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.Configuration;
import org.jbehave.core.configuration.MostUsefulConfiguration;
import org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InjectableStepsFactory;
import org.jbehave.core.steps.InstanceStepsFactory;

public class Sample extends JUnitStory {

@Override public Configuration configuration() {
    return new MostUsefulConfiguration();
}

@Override public InjectableStepsFactory stepsFactory() {
    return new InstanceStepsFactory(configuration(),
            new SampleSteps());
}
}
```

But if I run the Runner class using Junit, I get

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/thoughtworks/paranamer/Paranamer
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.<init>(Embedder.java:50)
at org.jbehave.core.embedder.Embedder.<init>(Embedder.java:60)
at org.jbehave.core.ConfigurableEmbedder.<init>    (ConfigurableEmbedder.java:40)
at org.jbehave.core.junit.JUnitStory.<init>(JUnitStory.java:16)
at com.kar.features.Sample.<init>(Sample.java:9)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:195)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:244)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:241)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thoughtworks.paranamer.Paranamer
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 27 more
```

It would be great if someone can help me resolving this issue.

Comment: I copied your code and .story, and ran it with no failure. What version of JBehave do you use? Are you using maven? I'm guessing your issue might be related to some missing dependencies.

Comment: Nope, I'm not using Maven, if possible can you please share the pom.xml file, so that I can try running using maven ?

Answer (score 0):

In general JBehave uses matching pattern for story runner. It looks for *Test* in class name. It could be explicitly configured in maven like this:

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.11</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
                    <include>**/When*.java</include>
                    <include>**/*TestSuite.java</include>
                </includes>
                <argLine>-Xmx512m</argLine>
                <parallel>classes</parallel>
                <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <webdriver.driver>${webdriver.driver}</webdriver.driver>
                </systemPropertyVariables>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```